# Positioning a DIV directly under 100% width auto-height fixed-position DIV

Tags: html, css

So, first post here, and I have been going nuts trying to figure out the answer to this problem.

I have two divs:

```
#splash {
width:100%;
min-width:1024px;
height:auto;
position:fixed;
top:80px;
z-index:-1;
}

#maincontentwrap {
width:100%;
min-width:1024px;
height:2000px;
z-index:100;
background:#838d82;
}
```

The idea I am trying to express is that I want #maincontentwrap to be positioned directly under #splash, but I want #maincontentwrap to remain fixed in position while #splash scrolls over it. I guess the problem lay in the fact that I'm trying to position something directly under another that has a varying height.

Any insight into this matter would be greatly appreciated. Two days of tinkering has not turned up much.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: This is probably an [xy question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to achieve and why?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `position: fixed` or `position: absolute` in your `#maincontentwrap` and adjust the margins and paddings accordling to the height of `#splash`.

If the height is determined at runtime, you should consider using JavaScript to calculate and set the margins for `#maincontentwrap`.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I just realized there are many ways to ask this question (a bit of a CSS/HTML/JQuery noob here, as I majored in graphic design and have been doing a lot of web lately). I think the solution will come in the form of using JQuery to get the height of #splash and making it the position/top margin of #maincontentwrap  but again not too sure.

Comment: Good to know I could help. I couldn't understand what you meant by
*"I want #maincontentwrap to remain fixed in position while #splash scrolls over it"*, but if my answer helped you, that's great. :)

Comment: I guess the best thing to do would be to show an example of the code in progress!
http://alexanderfitch.com/waywest/index.html
The idea would be for that gray/green box (#maincontentwrap) to appear flush below the big image (#splash) no matter what the width of the browser is